# Don't work vertical align with image in lightbox

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, lightbox

I want to center image in lightbox gallery with vertical-align: middle, but can't. Where I do mistake?
 
**html:**

```
<div><img src="images/image1.png"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
display: table-row;
/* or display: table; -> the result is the same for me */
height: 550px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
img {
display: table-cell;
max-height: 550px;
margin: 0 auto;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: can you post a demo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zzdhxv0w/ here is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzdhxv0w/2/)**

```
div {
   display: table-cell;
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #0f0;
    line-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
display:inline-block;
max-width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its works and I understand where I was wrong